# MongoDB $geoWithin statement doesn't work for wide ranges

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

The following doc:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56dd4fb755eb122ee622e17d"),
    "geo_segments" : {
        "type" : "MultiPoint",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            [ 
                90, 
                0
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Can be found using:

```
db.collection.find({
    "geo_segments": {
      $geoWithin: {
        $geometry: {
          type : "Polygon" ,
          coordinates: [ [
            [-131, -90], [-131, 90],
            [131, 90], [131, -90],
            [-131, -90]
          ] ]
        }
      }
    }
});
```

But nothing is found when I change all 131 occurences to 132:

```
db.collection.find({
    "geo_segments": {
      $geoWithin: {
        $geometry: {
          type : "Polygon" ,
          coordinates: [ [
            [-132, -90], [-132, 90], [132, 90], [132, -90], [-132, -90]
          ] ]
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Why this won't work? CRS feature also doesn't seem to work:

```
db.collection.find({
    "geo_segments": {
      $geoWithin: {
        $geometry: {
          type : "Polygon" ,
          coordinates: [ [
            [-132, -90], [-132, 90], [132, 90], [132, -90], [-132, -90]
          ] ],
          crs: {
            type: "name",
            properties: { name: "urn:x-mongodb:crs:strictwinding:EPSG:4326" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Field is indexed with `2dsphere`, Mongo is 3.3.1

**UPD:**

Tried to set points in reversed order to treat polygon as "include" area, with no results:

```
db.geo_series.find({
    "geo_segments": {
      $geoWithin: {
        $geometry: {
          type : "Polygon" ,
          coordinates: [ [
            [-132, -90], [132, -90], [132, 90], [-132, 90], [-132, -90]
          ] ]
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the [documentation says](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/), *"single ring Polygon in **counter-clockwise winding** "(sic)*

```js
db.geo_series.find({
    "geo_segments": {
      "$geoWithin": {
        "$geometry": {
          "type" : "Polygon" ,
          "coordinates": [ [
            [-132, -90],[132, -90], [132, 90], [-132, 90], [-132, -90]
          ] ],
          "crs": {
            "type": "name",
            "properties": { "name": "urn:x-mongodb:crs:strictwinding:EPSG:4326" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

So the direction the polygon is defined in is important, as is the "crs" since your polygon does extend beyond a single hemisphere.

FYI, your polygon is basically the same as the reference Polygon in the documentation in that is crosses hemispheres and reverse orders of longitude and latitude, but just over a slightly larger area.

Comment: Solved this by dividing large area into eight of small 90° x 90° segments and build $or statement from them. But why -132° to 132° dont work? Yes, It's larger than hemisphere, but -131° to 131° is also larger, it's 262°. I need to understand what is the math here.

Comment: @odiszapc Works for me just as displayed, and exactly how it's explained in the relevant manual page.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. I need to use counter-clockwise + crs for wide polygons. Now need to understand how to propagate CRS to Spring Data Mongo query builder...

Comment: @odiszapc That would be another question ( and notably not the one you asked here ), and one I'm sure is already answered here before. It's just building a `DBObject` in the form that is accepted by the query interface.